# Python requests SSL version

Tags: python, ssl, openssl

I am using the python `requests` module on Ubuntu 13.04. I keep getting the error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

When I use curl, it fails by default but succeeds with the `-3` option.

```
curl https://username:Password@helloworldurl -3
```

This leads me to believe that it is the SSL version, which I found may be badly supported on ubuntu while searching the error. I should also note that the same code works on a mac.

Sooo. How do I change or check the SSL version using python preferably with `requests`.

Note: the url is private and cannot be given out. Sorry.

Comment: Do you get the same output on other SSL-enabled sites?

Comment: It differs between sites. Firefox can access the data without special intervention.